# Export SSRS report in pdf format from SSIS

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssis

I've a situation, where I need to export a report from my report server to my local in pdf format **through SSIS package**.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done from a Script Task.  An example of this is below with C# as the language used.

- Add an HTTP Connection Manager.  For the Server URL enter the url for the report server.  You find this in Reporting Services Configuration Manager on the Web Service URL pane.  Make sure to **use credentials with the appropriate privileges**.  I recommend testing and verifying the before proceeding.
- Add a C# Script Task with the code below.  The `ServerURL` property will be the as follows:

Report server URL **+** ?/ **+** report name including the path with the SSRS folder **+** the command options (beginning with first `&rs` below).  In this case `Format=PDF` is for saving in PDF format.

```cs
// this will be the name that was given to the HTTP Connection manager when it was created
ConnectionManager conn = Dts.Connections["HTTP Connection Manager"];
HttpClientConnection httpConn = new HttpClientConnection(conn.AcquireConnection(null));

// location where PDF will be saved to
string outputPDF = @"C:\Test\NameOfReport.pdf";
httpConn.ServerURL = @"http://YourReportServer?/Folder of Report/Report Name&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:Toolbar=False";

// second parameter of true indicates to overwrite file
httpConn.DownloadFile(outputPDF, true);
```

Comment: For excel use rs:Format=EXCEL  ie .xls

Comment: @userfl89 Could you please provide example on how to add a parameter pass to the URL?

Comment: @KeithL Simply add "&<parametername>=<parametervalue>" at the end of the url.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Script Task in SSIS to export the report from SSRS. Take a look at the following blog post. It explains how to export an SSRS report via SSIS. https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/generate-pdf-report-from-ssis/

Also, this forum thread has some other examples: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d6ac1ba5-90a2-403b-898e-edaab3c7b270/generate-ssrs-pdf-from-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices